# apt-get broken...help

Tags: apt, permissions, package-management

I tried to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` using the terminal, but a "Microsoft Eula" screen poped up and I closed the terminal (now I know I should not have done it). After failing to "click" on the "ok" option of such screen. The result is that I broke apt-get...
I tried `apt-get install -f` and also `apt-get remove -f` but it did not work.

```
jan@jan-Satellite-C855:~$ apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
jan@jan-Satellite-C855:~$ apt-get remove -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I read the article ["What to do when apt-get fails"](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/48910) but nothing worked...

So, what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you shared, you are not executing apt-get as **root**. Try this:

```
jan@jan-Satellite-C855:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

or you could switch user to root and then run it:

```
jan@jan-Satellite-C855:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for jan:
root@jan-Satellite-C855:~# apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving simply means you do not have permissions to run `apt-get`. If this is a vanilla Ubuntu install, then there is no `root` user, to use `apt-get` with user `jan` you must do it with [`sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Another possible reason for this error is the existence of another process looking `/var/lib/dpkg`. Both the Software Centre and the Package Manager do it, you should always close them before using `apt-get` in a terminal.

Comment: I fixed it! I used 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and it worked